# Html changes won't stick - after more than a year

Tags: html, edit

I made an edit to the phone number this page:

http://goo.gl/Y3pEHZ

The phone number is in the top right, and in the footer.

When the page loads, the new/correct number appears for a moment, but the old one snaps back right after that.
This is a flat file, no database.

I have downloaded the entire site and done a search on the old number and it's not there. 
This edit was done over a year ago. I cannot figure it out.

Comment: It's probably from one of the JavaScripts on your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are implementing a script to your page that automatically replaces the text to the old number. With my Script blocker i found out that the script loaded from the url `avvo.com` is causing this. You should check this script / your contact data on this page and change it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the account this firm has with avvo.com has the correct information for the office, it appears that your page is being populated with data from that site as mentioned by leiter0499.